# Why can't we comment the methods which is deprecated instead of using deprecated annotation in java?

Tags: java, annotations

Lets say we have below methods which is deprecated. If there is no use of this particular method. why don't we remove it or comment this line of code?

```
/**
 * Does some thing in old style.
 *
 * @deprecated use {@link #new()} instead.  
 */
@Deprecated
public void old() {
// ...
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis IMHO its not a duplicate since the part of what Deprecation is specified in the linked question but the difference between the commented out code and annotated is not explained.

Comment: @nullpointer _This means that the author wants to remove this method, but didn't do this yet to not break backward compatibility._

Comment: Also @Deprecated annotation can be spotted by reflection for some reasons, for examle for logging (in the log file there will be a record that deprecated method is used)

Comment: @nullpointer - So, How would compiler get to know which new latest code has to be used instead of that deprecated? Because when I run the code the compiler automatically gives a suggestion to use new code instead of deprecated one.

Comment: *compiler automatically gives a suggestion to use new code instead of deprecated one.* no that's not true unless the method marked @Deprecated  has some implementation to share the intention.

Comment: @nullpointer Okei, got it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Marking the implementation with comments altogether removes its implementation. All the existing code using the method `old()` would start breaking.
- On the other hand, marking the code as `@Deprecated` serves a warning for such usages that a better alternative exists and the consumer should plan to move away from using this API before it is being cleaned up.